# R hash a column does not work using digest

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that contains a column which is the unique identifier and I will like to create a new column which is the hash value. 
I am using the transform from dplyr and digest for hashing but looks like all the hashed value are the same.

```
          status  identifier
1         NEW     1035656|8000|157.6|2018-12-10 00:00:00.0|2018-12-06 00:00:00.0
2         NEW     1852231|460000|1748.0|2018-03-09 00:00:00.0|2018-03-07 00:00:00.0
3         NEW     3197282|6000|55.2|2019-01-18 00:00:00.0|2019-01-16 00:00:00.0
4         NEW     1827398|396000|21859.2|2019-02-25 00:00:00.0|2019-02-21 00:00:00.0
5         NEW     1148967|60000|150.0|2018-10-15 00:00:00.0|2018-10-11 00:00:00.0
```

Output

```
data_new <- transform(data, hash=digest(identifier, algo="md5", serialize = F))
```

And the outcome looks wrong.

```
hash
1 d1ede7da2094651658adfd6171c33c52
2 d1ede7da2094651658adfd6171c33c52
3 d1ede7da2094651658adfd6171c33c52
4 d1ede7da2094651658adfd6171c33c52
5 d1ede7da2094651658adfd6171c33c52
6 d1ede7da2094651658adfd6171c33c52
```

Can someone explain to me what is wrong with me syntax?

Comment: `hash=digest(identifier,...)` computes it once on the entire column, not per-element. You need one of the `*apply` family, or equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a hash algorithm doesn't care how much input you give him, it compresses in your case your whole column and not the single value. The `digest` function is designed to hash whole columns/lists etc.  It hashes all it can get. So just for verification let's input your whole column at once:

```
digest( c("1035656|8000|157.6|2018-12-10 00:00:00.0|2018-12-06 00:00:00.0", "1852231|460000|1748.0|2018-03-09 00:00:00.0|2018-03-07 00:00:00.0",
          "3197282|6000|55.2|2019-01-18 00:00:00.0|2019-01-16 00:00:00.0", "1827398|396000|21859.2|2019-02-25 00:00:00.0|2019-02-21 00:00:00.0",
          "1148967|60000|150.0|2018-10-15 00:00:00.0|2018-10-11 00:00:00.0"), algo="md5", serialize= F)
```

It gives get the output like in your example. Since there is just one return value, the column gets filled with the same value.

```
 "d1ede7da2094651658adfd6171c33c52"
```

The solution is fairly simple, just use your hash on every row of the column like:

```
df$hash <-lapply(df$identifier, function(x) {digest(x, algo="md5", serialize = F)})
```

this gives the intendet output of:

```
   identifier                                                          hash
1  1035656|8000|157.6|2018-12-10 00:00:00.0|2018-12-06 00:00:00.0      d1ede7da2094651658adfd6171c33c52
2  1852231|460000|1748.0|2018-03-09 00:00:00.0|2018-03-07 00:00:00.0   ca4caeac0a702094d51a13e67f23e56a
3  3197282|6000|55.2|2019-01-18 00:00:00.0|2019-01-16 00:00:00.0       239342dba0ec56f3b4200cb36046f2e0
4  1827398|396000|21859.2|2019-02-25 00:00:00.0|2019-02-21 00:00:00.0  54ea74e4344c14f8708dc47425ee1995
5  1148967|60000|150.0|2018-10-15 00:00:00.0|2018-10-11 00:00:00.0     f6bb25b0d7c1fbb65117d9403dadc7d2
```

Answer (score 1):

simply:

```
data_new <- transform(data, hash=sapply(identifier,  digest, algo="md5", serialize = F,USE.NAMES = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

`rowwise()` in `dplyr 1.0.0` does the trick:

```
data <-
  tibble(
    identifier = c(
      "1035656|8000|157.6|2018-12-10 00:00:00.0|2018-12-06 00:00:00.0",
      "1852231|460000|1748.0|2018-03-09 00:00:00.0|2018-03-07 00:00:00.0",
      "3197282|6000|55.2|2019-01-18 00:00:00.0|2019-01-16 00:00:00.0",
      "1827398|396000|21859.2|2019-02-25 00:00:00.0|2019-02-21 00:00:00.0",
      "1148967|60000|150.0|2018-10-15 00:00:00.0|2018-10-11 00:00:00.0"
    )
  )

data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(hash = digest(identifier, algo="md5", serialize = F))
```

which returns

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
# Rowwise: 
  identifier                                                         hash                            
  <chr>                                                              <chr>                           
1 1035656|8000|157.6|2018-12-10 00:00:00.0|2018-12-06 00:00:00.0     d1ede7da2094651658adfd6171c33c52
2 1852231|460000|1748.0|2018-03-09 00:00:00.0|2018-03-07 00:00:00.0  ca4caeac0a702094d51a13e67f23e56a
3 3197282|6000|55.2|2019-01-18 00:00:00.0|2019-01-16 00:00:00.0      239342dba0ec56f3b4200cb36046f2e0
4 1827398|396000|21859.2|2019-02-25 00:00:00.0|2019-02-21 00:00:00.0 54ea74e4344c14f8708dc47425ee1995
5 1148967|60000|150.0|2018-10-15 00:00:00.0|2018-10-11 00:00:00.0    f6bb25b0d7c1fbb65117d9403dadc7d2
```